# Can't change attributes of button in view loaded from nib file

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, xib, nib

I am loading a view which I created inside the interface builder like this:

```
let contentView = Bundle.main.loadNibnamed("ContentView", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as! ContentView
```

The view contains an UIImageView and a UIButton. Both of them are connected with IBOutlets to the ContentView class file.

Now when I am loading the view I am setting the UIImageView's image which works fine. I am also trying to change the UIButton's text and backgroundColor but both won't change. Interestingly the button doesn't keep the color I set in the interface builder but the Text.

The code I am using to change the text and the color:

```
contentView.contentButton.backgroundColor = .red
contentView.contentButton.titleLabel?.text = "someText"
```

Thanks for the help.

```
ContentView.swift
class ContentView: UIView {
   @IBOutlet weak var mainImageView: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet weak var contentImageView: UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet weak var contentButton: UIButton! 
}
```

The code I am using to create the views:

```
ContentScrollViewController.swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 0..<imageArray.count {
        let xPosition = Int(self.view.frame.width) * i

        let contentView: ContentView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ContentView", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as! ContentView

        contentView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: -Int((self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!))

        contentView.mainImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        contentView.contentImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "stoerer_png_neu")

        //Not working 
        contentView.specialButton.backgroundColor = .red

        if let url = URL(string: imageArray[i]) {
            contentView.mainImageView.af_setImage(withURL: url)
        }

        mainScrollView.contentSize.width = mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)

        mainScrollView.addSubview(contentView)
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm assuming `ContentView` is a `UIView` subclass? If so, is it set as the XIB's *FIle's Owner* or as the Custom Class of the View in the XIB?

Comment: Yes ContentView is a UIView subclass and it is set as the custom class of the view in the .xib.

Comment: You might want to double-check all of your IBOutlet connections, or maybe re-start your `ContentView` from scratch. I'm following your code, and the way you set your IBOutlets, and I'm not having any trouble.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After restarting all files connected to the problem I finally managed to find the issue. Somehow the constraints of the UIButton in .xib were responsible for the issue. So if you are experiencing the same please check your constraints. :]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
contentView.contentButton.setTitle("someText", for: .normal)
```

and

```
contentView.contentButton.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
```

because you need to set those attributes for a specific UIControlState

For the background you need to use the layer:

```
contentView.contentButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

Comment: The solution for setting the text works but the second one changes only the titleColor and not the UIButtons backgroundColor.

Comment: Sadly setting the layers backgroundColor to a cgColor doesn't work for me.

Comment: contentView.contentButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor or do you need anything else?

Comment: @Maci do you use an backgroundImage or something else? because this will normally working and I tested this before 10 minutes. Is there an error or is it just not working?

Comment: No I am not using an backgroundImage for the button.

Comment: @Maci Then this is another problem. This is the way to change the backgroundColor of an UIButton

Comment: Yeah but what could the problem be? Nevertheless thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Yes I am calling the code after super.viewDidLoad(). I already tried placing it in viewWillAppear()/viewDidAppear().

Comment: @Maci try contentView.contentButton.setNeedsDisplay() or setNeedsLayout() or contentView.setNeedsDisplay() or setNeedsLayout(). When this is not working I can't help without seeing the complete project.

Comment: I will upload the affected files as soon as possible.